# Can I use Commons CLI to commands line without - flags?

Tags: java, command-line-interface, apache-commons-cli

I don't know if I was clear, but I want to use Commons CLI without flags with minus, like -t or --args.

In fact I want to use it as the IRC commands.

In the example:

```
Options options = new Options();
options.addOption("send", false, "send text");
```

I created a option with -send.  Could I create it without the minus?

Thank you all.

Comment: As a side note: from the Apache Commons CLI API documentation related to [`Options#addOption(String opt, boolean hasArg, String description) )`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/cli/Options.html#addOption(java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20java.lang.String)) (emphasis mine): "opt - Short **single-character** name of the option".

Comment: `addOption()` is overloaded, and there is also variant that allows to provide [BOTH short and long options](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/cli/Options.html#addOption(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20java.lang.String))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieve this changing the source code. In a certain part of the code is verified if the "--" is used. Remove this made the solution.

However I see that the best was develop my own code. If someone need a simple code to parse "arg arg1" format here it is.

https://github.com/faelcorreia/SimpleCLI